# Finding the location off the nose of an 3d object

Tags: 3d

Alright, so say I have an airplane in a 3d space. It is capable of yaw, roll, pitch, and has an XYZ/ENU location in the universe. I'm trying to find the coordinates of a point # units in front of it. How do I figure out where that point is going to be?

I.e: My plane is flying perfectly straight and narrow, pointing directly north. It is currently 0ft east, 0 ft north, and 1000ft up. I know that a point 2000ft in front of it is going to be 0ft east, 2000ft north, and 1000ft up. But how do I account for the various angles that the plane can turn when finding this point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say the plane is pointing down the zAxis when it's transformation matrix is identity.  Extract the zAxis vector from your transformation matrix, multiply it by your offset, and add it onto the plane's nose.

Comment: Hmm, thanks for the start. Now I just have to figure out what all of that means and I should be good. Though can you explain any on how I find which axis it's pointing down? (Don't mean to be a pest, I'm just bad with 3D math and got stuck with solving this problem.)

Comment: There is no fixed standard for coordinate axes in 3D graphics.  Tradition would mean is probably -Y or -Z.  The easiest thing to do would be to ask the person who made models for it, or the person who made the camera.  Failing that you would have look at the 3D models themseleves.  This seems like a simple question, but in reality it can be anything, as long as the models and camera are made using the same rules beause any axis can point 'down' as 'down' doesn't mean anything when you're floating in space.